# $_SESSION and WordPress struggle

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to achieve something that I've not tried before with WordPress, to try and avoid having a very complex category structure.

**What I'm trying to do is:**

When the site is visited, there is a variable that is declared but left as NULL. Upon visiting a page that uses a certain template, lets say 'template-x.php'. The variable is set according to a hook on the page. I.e user visits 'Shop X' and the variable is set to 'Shop X'. In another template, I then want to filter what is displayed, based on the variable.

**The actual usage would be:**

My client has 4 shops, and wants a selection of products for each shop. They want their products to be in one place, and tagged to the shop they apply to. The products are split into 4 types. So, 4 shops all with 4 product types each.

I want to avoid having to make a category for each shop product type, resulting in 20 categories.

Therefore, my idea would be to use this variable to further filter the products. So they visit the shop page, click product type 1, and the template uses the variable to only show product type 1 that are tagged with that shop.

Is $_SESSION the right way to go about this? I have been trying for a few days now to get it to work, with no avail.

Many thanks in advance.

Steve

Comment: 4 X 4 != 20, btw. In all seriousness though, I've learned that for anything under 30, doing it manually is usually quicker. In your case, making 16 categories is probably infinitely easier. You're also likely to open a world of hurt modifying WordPress like that. 2 cents.

Comment: What e-commerce plugin are you using and why?

Comment: 4 x 4 plus the 4 shops. I guess you're right. I was hoping to make it as simple as possible for the client to understand when using WordPress to edit/create new products. There is no e-commerce plugin, just posts and categories.

Comment: So what's the "type" you want to filter? That's is to say, are you using tags, some other attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [List category posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) plugin.

Assign product(s) with a tag, ie, store1.

Then on a page in store 1 add this code to the HTML:

```
[catlist tags=store1]
```

You could also do tags like, widgets, whatsits, and thingambobs:
Then on each store, edit the pages:

```
//store 1, widgets and thingamabobs:
[catlist tags=widgets,thingamabobs]
//store 2, whatsits:
[catlist tags=whatsits]
//store 3, some_category products:
[catlist name=some_category]
```

There are lots of other options on the [Other Notes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/) page.

Comment: I like this as a solution. It would mean having a page for each of the store's 4 product categories, but I can live with that. Thanks sudopeople!